# NSString in the Middle of a Label

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

How do I make it so that the label will read: "about 30 minutes", where the value of an NSString "scoreString" is 30?

Here is what I have to display the string alone:

```
NSString *scoreString = [[score objectForKey:@"score"] stringValue];
testLabel.text = scoreString;
```

I just need a way to write the "about" and then the scoreString and then "minutes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a new string which combines each component.  There are a few ways to do it, but this is probably the easiest:

```
testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"about %@ minutes", scoreString];
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I'll give you the check once it allows me.